# Toggle between interactive and non-interactive modes

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a `checkBoxInput` to toggle between interactive and non-interactive modes. With an `actionButton` I can control the output to wait for the inputs. But I would like to create a toggle to change this action of the `actionButton`.

For example, when the interactive mode is on using the `checkBoxInput`, I would like Shiny to create output without requiring the `actionButton` and when the interactive mode is off, I would like Shiny to wait for the `actionButton`.

###### Example 1

I've tried to create an example here, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
library (shiny) 

vars <- setdiff(names(iris), "Species")

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Interactive and non-interactive mode'),
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxInput('check', "Interactive Mode", value = FALSE),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', vars),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', vars, selected = vars[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3, min = 1, max = 9),
    actionButton('run', "Run")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- eventReactive(input$run, {
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })
  
  
  clusters <- reactive({
    req(input$run)
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
    
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

###### Example 2 (This example works? but not sure - requires further testing)

I'm wondering if I sounded confusing so I've made a more simple example and renamed interactive mode as "instant mode". I'd love to know how to make the larger app work with the `isolate` concept.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxInput("instant", label = "Instant Mode", value = TRUE),
    selectInput("input1", label = NULL, choices = names(iris)),
    actionButton("run", "Run")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("values_print"),
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    if(input$instant) {
      boxplot(iris[[input$input1]], horizontal = TRUE)
    } else {
      req(input$run)
      isolate(boxplot(iris[[input$input1]], horizontal = TRUE))
    }

  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that this answer is not perfect but I had a few minutes and this is what I came up with:

```
library (shiny) 

vars <- setdiff(names(iris), "Species")

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Interactive and non-interactive mode'),
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxInput('check', "Interactive Mode", value = FALSE),
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', vars),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', vars, selected = vars[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3, min = 1, max = 9),
    actionButton('run', "Run")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  values <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    values$selectedData=iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    values$clusters=kmeans(values$selectedData, input$clusters)
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$check)
    values$selectedData=iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    values$clusters=kmeans(values$selectedData, input$clusters)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
    
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(req(values$selectedData),
         col = values$clusters$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(values$clusters$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I made the Cluster count dependent on the `actionButton` as well which wasn't the case in your example. The only issue is that the plot does "react" when selecting the `checkBoxInput` initially. Let me know what you think. As mentioned at the beginning, I suspect there is a better solution.

**Update**

See comment on using `shinyjs` below. This example uses `toggleState` which is equivalent to `enable`/`disable` with an if statement. To hide use `show`/`hide`.

```
library (shiny)
library(shinyjs)

vars <- setdiff(names(iris), "Species")

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Interactive and non-interactive mode'),
    sidebarPanel(
        useShinyjs(),
        checkboxInput('check', "Interactive Mode", value = FALSE),
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', vars),
        selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', vars, selected = vars[[2]]),
        numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3, min = 1, max = 9),
        actionButton('run', "Run")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput('plot1')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    values <- reactiveValues()
    
    observeEvent(input$check, {
        toggleState('run')
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    observeEvent(input$run, {
        values$selectedData=iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
        values$clusters=kmeans(values$selectedData, input$clusters)
    })
    
    observe({
        req(input$check)
        values$selectedData=iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
        values$clusters=kmeans(values$selectedData, input$clusters)
    })
    
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        
        palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
                  "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
        
        par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
        plot(req(values$selectedData),
             col = values$clusters$cluster,
             pch = 20, cex = 3)
        points(values$clusters$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
    })
    
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: One could easily use the shinyjs package (https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/) to disable/hide the Run actionButton during interactive mode if desired. I can update my answer if that is something you would find useful.

Comment: Please see updated question with `Example 2`

Comment: I added an example using shinyjs. Looking at Example 2 shortly

Comment: Seems to be answered in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you looking for.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    #checkboxInput("instant", label = "Instant Mode", value = TRUE),
    radioButtons(inputId = "instant", label = "Mode", choices = c("Instant","Not Instant"), selected = character(0)),
    selectInput("input1", label = NULL, choices = names(iris)),
    actionButton("run", "Run")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(cntr=0)

  observeEvent(input$run,{
    if (input$instant=="Instant") { rv$cntr <- 0
    }else {
      rv$cntr <- 1
    }
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$instant)
    if (input$instant=="Instant") {
      rv$cntr <- 0
      p <- boxplot(iris[[input$input1]], horizontal = TRUE)
    }else {
      input$run
      print(rv$cntr)
      if (rv$cntr==1){
        p <- boxplot(iris[[input$input1]], horizontal = TRUE)
      } else p <- NULL
    }
    p
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please see updated question with `Example 2`

Comment: @TyperWriter, I am not sure I understand the behavior you are expecting.  Do you expect to see no plot until you click on the actionButton when the instant checkboxInput is unchecked?  In that case, it is better to use radioButtons instead of checkboxInput.

Comment: Yes, that's right. When the instant checkboxInput is unchecked, I would like to use the actionButton to generate plots. I hadn't thought about radioButtons, but that sounds promising.

Comment: This seems to be working well, except when I return to not instant, it is stuck on instant mode.

Comment: Once you select a radioButton value, it can only be instant (auto plot) or Not Instant (no plot until you click on RUN).  You cannot switch between Instant and Not Instant?